# NGINX+NODE JS - no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am getting following error in error.log file nginx conf file.

I am trying to run nginx server on to of node js server.

> Error : no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client:
>   127.0.0.1, server: www.XYZ.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://localhost/", host: "localhost"

Node js server is running on port 3000 and nginx on port 80

nginx conf file is

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  128;

    #gzip  on;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    client_header_timeout 3000;
    client_body_timeout 3000;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
    client_max_body_size 32m;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k; 


    server {
        listen 80 ;
        server_name XYZ.com;
        location / {
         # Base url of the Data Science Studio installation
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        }
    }



}
```

and node js server is running on port 3000

```
    app.listen(3000);
```

It looks like nginx is trying to connect to node js server on dafault port 80 and not 3000.
    Please help me with the issue. I have spend lot of time on it but no luck.

Thanks

Comment: I think this isse is with your node server not up in time can you add ` proxy_read_timeout 5m; ` in the nginx file

Comment: Please run `nginx -T` and make sure you are not getting some other config also

Comment: I tried both the options I am still getting the error :upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.XYZ.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://[::1]:80/", host: "localhost"

Comment: Add the output of `nginx -T` and `sudo netstat -plant` to your question

Answer (score 0):

For me, I fixed it by move proxy_pass to the end of config block after proxy_set_header.